# Interpreting tensor indexing

Tags: numpy, matrix

I am trying to index a matrix using

```
import numpy as np

z = np.array([[0,1,0],[1,0,0]])
phi = np.array([[0.8,0.2],[0.1,0.9]])

w = phi[z]
print(w)`
```

The result is

```
[[[0.8 0.2]
  [0.1 0.9]
  [0.8 0.2]]

 [[0.1 0.9]
  [0.8 0.2]
  [0.8 0.2]]]
```

Can some one explain how the indexing works here?
Help much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: `z` is picking rows from `phi`  What did you want?

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for visiting my question. That's exactly what I wanted.